# How can I reenable bluetooth without a keyboard or mouse?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, mouse, bluetooth, boot-camp

I accidentally turned bluetooth off while using Windows 10 in a bootcamp partition and now I can't reenable it, as I'm using a bluetooth keyboard and mouse. Is there any way I can bluetooth back on without a wired mouse or keyboard?

Comment: Without some remote desktop software you are unlikely to be able to. If it is Windows 10 Pro you may be in luck and be able to access it from another machine or phone, but it may have to already have been enabled. https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4028379/windows-10-how-to-use-remote-desktop

Comment: Can't you borrow a wired keyboard or mouse from someone to undo the changes?